# how to convert vectors into matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a problem with making matrix.
I have an array 10x10 and 2 figures: a and b (3 and 5).
It is first point of my square (which has size 5x5).
I will mark my square by "1" on my vector.

I would like to have something like this:

```
[0000000000
 0000000000
 0000000000
 0000000000
 0011111000
 0011111000
 0011111000
 0011111000
 0011111000
 0000000000]
```

How I should put points x(i) and y(i) into a matrix?
I will be very thankful for your help.
I wrote simple code and now I don't know how I can make a matrix from it.

```
a=3; %x 
b=5; %y 
i=0; 
j=0;
dl_boku = 5;
%square
for i=1:10
    if (i < a) || (i > a + (dl_boku - 1))
       x(i) = 0;
    else
       x(i) = 1;
    end
end

for i=1:10
    if (i < b) || (i > b + (dl_boku - 1))
        y(i) = 0;
    else
        y(i) = 1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this in MATLAB, and which is best will depend on the size of your grid and how sparse it is. I'll offer this solution:

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
dl_boku = 5;
dim = 10; % The size of your grid

[Y,X] = meshgrid(a:a+dl_boku-1,b:b+dl_boku-1); % Get indices of the 1's
matrix = sparse(X,Y,1,dim,dim);
```

For the size of your problem, the nested for loops are just about as quick, but as you scale up the problem (say, `a=30`, `b=50`, `dl_boku=25`, `dim=1000`), this implementation takes 0.004 seconds compared to 0.0141 for the nested for loops (averaged across 3 trials). The sparse implementation will also save space as the problem scales (assuming the matrix remains sparse)

EDIT:
Another word about scalability to emphasize the difference between the implementations, if you go with the nested for loops for whatever reason, it pays to declare the matrix variable and preallocate the space, i.e. `matrix = zeros(dim);`  Just for fun, I tried running the nested for loops with `a=300`, `b=500`, `dl_boku=250`, `dim=5000`... without preallocation it took 66 seconds to run. With preallocation, 0.35 seconds. The sparse implementation took 0.003 for this example. In terms of space, the sparse implementation uses 1040008 bytes in this example whereas the full matrix requires 200000000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

So finally from this code you have two vectors:

```
x =

     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

y =

     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

To obtain the matrix you presented in your question, you need only `x` and additional vector of `zeros`. So it will look like this:

```
z=zeros(1,10)
result_matrix=[z;z;z;z;x;x;x;x;x;z]
```

And you have your matrix:

```
result_matrix =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to automatically generate your matrix, you can use nested for loops like the following:

```
a = 3;
b = 5;
dl_boku = 5;
for i = 1:10
    for j = 1:10
        if lt(j,a) || gt(j,a+(dl_boku-1)) || lt(i,b) || gt(i,b+(dl_boku-1))
            matrix(i,j) = 0;
        else
            matrix(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Here, you won't have to initialize i or j, since the for loops will do that for you.